# Ruby on rails where clause not finding correct records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, dump

I have a rails model which is set up like this:

Poi:

```
id : int
name : varchar
subtype : int
```

I recently migrated a lot of records from one database to another using mysql_dump and import. The migration seemed to have gone well, and if I query an id in the console it finds that records. There is a record like this:

```
id : 33
name : testpoi
subtype : 172
```

If I try to find it using:

```
Poi.where(:subtype => 172).first
```

it always returns nil

If I run this exact query on the system from which I migrated the database it does work.

If I run `Poi.find(33)` it finds it too. I've tried

```
Poi.where(:subtype => "172").first
```

as well to make sure its not a datatype mismatch, but to no avail.

Also, if I add this object to a collection

```
@otherobject.poilist << Poi.find(33) #=> which has a has many with foreign key subtype
```

it works just fine (returns true after saving), but if I then restart the production console the association no longer exists, even though the subtype id matches the id of the containing object.

Comment: What does `Poi.find(33).subtype` returns?

Comment: it returns "172" (as i'd expect)

Comment: I wouldn't expect `Poi#subtype` to return a `String` if `subtype` was an `Integer` column in the database. Please explain why you expect it to be a `String`. Furthermore: Are there `enum` or `validate` definitions in your model? Please post your model.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same db where the records actually are and not to a development environment that is empty?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. It turned out that due to some funky migrations the subtype field was indeed a string. The real miracle here is that in some cases it DID work, because it shouldn't have. Case closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the replies. It turned out that due to some funky migrations the subtype field was indeed a string. The real miracle here is that in some cases it DID work, because it shouldn't have. Case closed!